# I need to be able to cross reference two database fields

Tags: php, if-statement

I need to cross examine two database fields for a yes/no result.

Just wondering if the below makes sense with what I need to do.

```
((a + b) + c = d) if a + b are true and c is also true then return Yes
((a + b) + c = d) if a + b are false and c is false then return No
((a + b) + c = d) if a + b are true and c is false then return No
((a + b) + c = d) if a + b are false and c is false then return No
```

pseudo code aside,

I need to be able to turn this into PHP, if I remove b from the equation I return a result perfectly fine but adding additional checks just returns blank.

```
@if ($report->subjectid == '2' && $report->subjectid == '3' && $report->metprogress == '1') Yes

   @elseif ($report->subjectid === '2' && $report->subjectid == '3' && $report->metprogress == '4' or
            $report->subjectid === '2' && $report->subjectid == '3' && $report->metprogress == '5') No

@endif</td>
```

This is the current code I have which obviously doesn't correlate with the pseudo code as I'm trying to figure out the actual structure I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your 2nd and 4th row is the same? ((a + b) + c = d) if a + b are false and c is false then return No

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with math.  It's nothing more than grammar school arithmetic.

Comment: What does "if a+b are true" mean?  One minute these look like numbers, the next they're booleans.  Voting to close because it's unclear what you're asking and not about math.

Comment: I'm unsure how you think the numbers 2 and a 3 are booleans. The title is wrong or I'm barking up the wrong tree. All I'm trying to do is look at a db field which is filled with numbers.

Subjectid = Subject table

2 = Math
3 = English

MetProgress = Subject Results Table

1 = A
2 = B
3 = C
and so on.

I need to see if Maths and English are attached and if they're results for said subjects are 3 and above then return Yes, if not return No.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are asking.

But I would suggest that it's not possible for this expression to evaluate to TRUE:

```
$report->subjectid == '2' && $report->subjectid == '3'
```

If the object property `subjectid` is equal to `'2'`, it cannot also be equal to `'3'`. And vice versa. At least one of those conditions won't evaluate to TRUE. And that means the result of the logical AND operation will never evaluate to TRUE.